# How to filter array of objects in Angular 7 from a list of checkboxes using a pipe

Tags: javascript, angular

I am looking to return a list animals that are filtered according to checkboxes the user selects (age, breed, animal type -- cat or dog, etc..); however, I am having trouble getting a new list/array of animals to only be displayed on the screen when a user selects a checkbox.

I am able to get all the animals (running locally I have 12 animals, 6 cats and 6 dogs) to display at first. Now my problem is getting some animals to disappear upon a user selecting to only display dogs. The lsit does not update and all animals are still shown.

I have tried nearly everything on stack overflow. I am able to get the search criterion to be sent to the pipe, but not the list of animals gotten from my json-server.

I've put in multiple console.logs() to debug and see what data is going where.

Background: 
DisplayAnimalsComponent comprises of two components: 1) FiltersComponent, 2) ProfileSquaresComponent. DisplayAnimalsComponent has no logic and the HTML is only the tag for the two composed components listed as 1 & 2.

First when this all loads, all animals are loaded by using a service which gets all the animals from a GET request and displays them. It assigns all the GET responses to a variable: animals. This is done in the ngOnInit() of ProfileSquaresComponent.

Upon a user click a checkbox in the FiltersComponent HTML, it sends that to the ProfileSquaresComponent method of ngOnChange() to then be pushed to a component variable -- filterCriteria -- then it sends the list of animals (as assigned in the ngOnInit()) and the list of criteria -- filterCriteria as list above) to the filterAnimals pipe.

I am not able to get the list of animals to send to the pipe.

Profile Squares Component: the actual tiles of animals a user clicks on to go to their profile

```
ngOnInit() {
    return this.displayAdoptablesService.getAnimals()
      .subscribe((res: any[]) => {
        this.animals = res;
        console.log('Animals init: ', this.animals);
      });
  }

  ngOnChange(filter) {
    this.filterCriteria.push(filter);
    console.log('Adding to filterCriteria: ', this.filterCriteria);

    this.animals = this.filterAnimalsPipe.transform(this.animals, this.filterCriteria);
    console.log('Animals change: ', this.animals);
  }
```

Filters Component: the checkboxes a user can check to choose to display certain animals

```
public updateFilters(filterCriteria: string) {
    const lowerFilter = filterCriteria.toLowerCase();
    // this.profileSquares.filterCriteria.push(lowerFilter);
    this.profileSquares.ngOnChange(lowerFilter);
  }
```

Filter Animals Pipe: the pipe which is to take the list of all animals, and the list of checked checkboxes and filter the list of all animals to return to the Profile Squares Component for displaying in the DisplayAnimalsComponent.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterAnimals'
})
export class FilterAnimalsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(animals: any[], searchCriterion: any[]): any {

    console.log('Search criterian: ', searchCriterion);
    console.log('Animals criterian: ', animals);

    if (!animals) {
      return [];
    }

    if (!searchCriterion) {
      return animals;
    }

    return animals.filter(animal => animal.type === searchCriterion);

  }
}
```

I expect for a user to be shown all animals upon page load.

Then if a user were to select to only see Dogs, then all other animals disappear. If a user were to select another filter like Young, the only Young Dogs would be shown.

Comment: Could you create a https://stackblitz.com/ project to show us a sample of your code, maybe with a mock object? Anyway, I don't think it's a best practice to use pipes like that, althought I know it works.

Comment: Sure, I will create one. What would be the recommended way to use pipes then? That is the only way I am familiar with. I look forward to learning their proper use.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes take a look to "Parameterizing a pipe". They should be used inside your template. Anyway, I'll wait for your stackblitz to help you a little bit more ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to get it working in Plnkr. Any other way I might be able to sne dit on over?